# Add headers to multiple text files SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a process that I want to create in SSIS. What I have so far is below.[image]

So the scenario is that a number of different file types are downloaded to a specific location - which has been created as a variable "RootFolder"
Within that RootFolder, is a folder called "Archive"

The first part of the process is to create a folder within the variable of ArchiveFolder, which is basically todays date.
Then in a For Loop Container, it copies all the files in the RootFolder to the Archive Folder. So we have a history of the files received.

The next step that I want to carry out in SSIS is to add a header line at the top of each of those text files. So all the files that still exist in the Root Folder get a header added to the top of the file. Is there something direct in SSIS to do this, or would I need a .bat file to do it and have an Execute Process Task, to call that bat file. Either way I have no idea how to achieve this bit. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Also how would I add the header of the file to be the filename?

Comment: I would do this with a Script Task, in which I would use the FileSystemObject to edit the file.

Comment: So how would I actually do that please as I have no idea how to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: start here:  https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=how+to+edit+a+text+file+from+.net&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=how+to+edit+a+text+file+from+.net&gs_l=hp...0i22i30l4.0.0.0.7885...........0.-D8JgKQ_0x4

Comment: Thanks but that is totally above me - I have no experience at all with C#. Will have to just tell work I can't do this as this is way above my skill set. Thanks for taking the time to reply.